# Munkres' Topology, exercise 22.4 (a)

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing

[image]

I want to prove $g$ is a quotient map and $X^*=\{g^{-1}(\{r\}):r\in \mathbb{R}$, then we know that there exists a homeomorphism from $X^* \to \mathbb{R}$. To prove continuity of $g$, I tried to prove for each $(x_0,y_0) \in \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ and each neighborhood $V$ of $g(x_0,y_0)$, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $(x_0,y_0)$ such that $g(U)\subset V.$

So, I suppose $(x_0,y_0) \in  \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ and $V$ is a neighborhood of $g(x_0,y_0)$. Then $(x_0,y_0) \in g^{-1}(V) = A\times B$ for some $A,B \in \mathbb{R}$. Hence $x_0 \in A$ and $y_0 \in B$.

Then I want to say that there exists open interval $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ such that $x_0 \in (a,b) \subset A$ and $y_0 \in (c,d) \subset B$. Thus $g(( a,b), (c,d)) \subset V$.

I don't know if I can say there exists open interval $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ such that $x_0 \in (a,b) \subset A$ and $y_0 \in (c,d) \subset B$. If I want to say that, what statement supports this?

Answer (score 1):

By Theorem 18.4, the map $h:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ given by $h(x,y)=(x,y^2)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ is continuous since each of its coordinate functions $h_1(x,y)= x,$ $h_2(x,y)= y^2$ is continuous. (The first coordinate function $h_1:\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R},$ $h_1(x,y)=x$ is a projection, hence continuous. And the other coordinate function $h_2:\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is given by $h_2(x,y)=y^2,$ which is continuous by Theorem 21.5.)

Moreover, the addition map $\mu:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},$ $\mu(x,y)=x+y$ is continuous by Lemma 21.4.

Hence the composition $g=\mu\circ h$ given by
$$  g(x,y)=\mu\circ h(x,y)=x+y^2$$
for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous map being a composition of continuous maps.

Comment: I doubt you can use Theorem 18.4 to claim the function $h$ you defined is continuous. After the proof of Theorem 18.4, the author mentioned that "There is no useful criterion for the continuity of a map $f : A \times B \to X$ whose domain is a product space. One might conjecture that $f$ is continuous if it is continuous 'in each variable separately,' but this conjecture is not true. (See Exercise 12.)" And it seems that you didn't follow the statement in Theorem 18.4. The function $f$ in Theorem is $f:A \to X\times Y$ but you said $h:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Is it better to use Theorem 21.5 to argue that $y^2= y\cdot y$ (multiplication) is continuous, then apply Theorem 21.5 again to deduce $x+y^2$ (addition) is continuous?

Comment: I'm using Theorem 18.4 as in this case $h:A\to X\times Y$ with $A=\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R},$ $X=Y=\mathbb{R}.$ Then the coordinate functions of $h$ are $h_1:\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $h_1(x,y)=x,$ which is a projection hence continuous, and $h_2:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $h_2(x,y)=y^2$  is continuous by your argument of Theorem 21.5.